# Using ioredis node package in NodeJS application to store data in cache but unable to set TTL for key

Tags: node.js, caching, redis, ttl, ioredis

I'm sitting with an issue with my NodeJS application using the ioredis node package. I set a value in cache with a ttl, after it is set, I console log the ttl of the key using 'client.ttl(key)' and it returns the ttl but when I then go to my redis-cli (they are both connected on the same port) and query it with TTL key, then I get -1, meaning the key exists but with no ttl and in fact the key-value pair still exists after the set ttl. What could be the cause of this?

Here is my session-cache.js file:

```
import Redis from 'ioredis';

const client = new Redis({
  db: 0,
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 6379
});

export const cache = {
  async get(key) {
    const value = await client.get(key);
    return JSON.parse(value);
  },

  async set(key, value, ttl) {
    if (ttl) {
      await client.set(key, value, "EX", ttl);
      // await client.expire(key, ttl)
      console.log(await client.ttl(key));
    } else {
      await client.set(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    }
  },
  async delete(key) {
    await client.del(key);
  },

  async ttl(key) {
    client.ttl(key, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      } else {
        console.log('TTL:', result);
      }
    });
  }

}
```

Here is the block of code that first sets the session cache:

```
export async function initiateSessionCache(requestObject) {
  let sessionCache = await cache.get(requestObject.msisdn);
  // set initial session cache if session cache is falsy (session cache is empty)
  if (!sessionCache) {
    const initialState = {
      outerState: 'start',
      innerState: 'requestId',
    };
    sessionCache = {
      state: initialState,
      requests: [],
      // create state stack to track user's state and allow user to go back to previous state
      stateStack: [initialState]
    };
    await cache.set(requestObject.msisdn, sessionCache);
  }
  return sessionCache;
}
```

The ttl is returned from the session-cache.js file but outside of that, when calling ttl method on the client for the key, it returns -1. I've read that it may take a few moments before the ttl is properly set but I still get the same result.

Could it be that my redis.config file is not set-up correctly? I am using Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not calling your `cache.set` method correctly. It takes three arguments—the key, the value, and the TTL—but you are only passing in two:

```js
await cache.set(requestObject.msisdn, sessionCache);
```

Shouldn't this be:

```js
await cache.set(requestObject.msisdn, sessionCache, 60);
```

But perhaps I'm not fully understanding the problem. If that is the case, it's also worth noting that if you call SET on a key with EX and then call SET on it again without one, the TTL will be removed. For example:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> SET foo bar EX 60
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> TTL foo
(integer) 58
127.0.0.1:6379> SET foo baz
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> FOO foo
(integer) -1
```

Perhaps this is the source of your problem.

Comment: I do re-set the cache after it has been set with the TTL. Is there any way I can work around this? Or should I completely change the cache manager I use?

Comment: Can you just pass in the TTL each time?

Comment: no unfortunately not. I save my 'sessionCache' as an object with a unique key which is passed in from a post request to my endpoint. I just add properties to be saved to the specific sessionCache then set it in the cache again.

Comment: Do you want it to reset the ttl whenever you update the cache or do you want to the ttl to continue to count down when you make a change?

Comment: I would like the TTL to continue to count down after I've made the change. However, because of the time pressure of the task I am just resetting the TTL each time which is working.